# Twilio Android getMembers returns null

Tags: android, twilio

I'm implementing Twilio's Programmable Chat using the Android SDK.

When the Chat is setup I create a new Channel (using `channelBuilder()`), and then join it (calling `join()`). Then I set the channel listener and I call `channel.getMembers().inviteByIdentity(userId)` but that crashes because channel.getMembers() returns null.

Do I have to call `inviteByIdentity(userId)` on a different place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved `channel.getMembers().inviteByIdentity(userId)` to `ChannelListener.onSynchronizationChanged(Channel channel)` method and it now works!

Should have tried this before…